# Multiprocessing queue deadlock

Tags: python

The following code blocks and does not let the program exit:

```
import multiprocessing

q = multiprocessing.Queue()

for i in range(10000):
    q.put("x" * 1000)

# Un-commenting the next line lets the program exit
# q.close()

print("trying to exit")
```

I've run it many times with Python 3.6 and 3.7 using the official docker images, in Docker for Mac, and each time I had to interrupt it (`Ctrl+C`).

The stack trace suggests a deadlock during the finalization of the queue:

```
^CError in atexit._
run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 265, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 189, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 192, in _finalize_join
    thread.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1044, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Remarks:

- this is obviously a very small subset of the actual program that made me discover this behavior
- emptying the queue (calling `q.get_nowait` until `queue.Empty`) does not help
- putting fewer or smaller items in the queue lets the program exit
- adding a `q.close()` also lets the program exit
- same with a `q = None`, which lets the queue be garbage-collected (and thus `.close`d)

Questions:

- am I doing something wrong?
- is there an implicit limit on the total size of the elements in a `multiprocessing.Queue`?
- `multiprocessing.Queue.close` is documented as "usually unnecessary for most code"; in what cases is it necessary? It seems very necessary in my case. Why?
- is this just a bug in `multiprocessing.Queue`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing

q = multiprocessing.Queue()

for i in range(10000):
    q.put("x" * 1000)



# Un-commenting the next line lets the program exit
# q.close()

print("trying to exit")

for i in range(100000):
    print(q.get())
```

even this is working but if you close the q by q.close(), how will the multiprocessing will put items in closed q.

[image]

i am not getting such errors.

Comment: i am not getting such errors

Comment: if i am not getting such errors , i can't help.